# Ubuntu 14.04 CUDA 8.0 unmet dependency

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda, dependencies, circular-dependency

I am trying to upgrade my cuda libraries the newest Cuda 8.0.61.
I started of with removing cuda 7.5.
Later on I have downloaded the deb file of cuda 8.0.61 and run the following commands:

1. `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64.deb`
2. `sudo apt-get update`
3. `sudo apt-get install cuda`

During the installation I received an error and when I try to run `sudo apt-get install -f`, I get the following dependency error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cuda-cublas-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cublas-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-cudart-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cudart-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-cufft-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cufft-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-curand-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-curand-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-cusolver-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cusolver-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-cusparse-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-cusparse-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-npp-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-npp-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-nvgraph-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-nvgraph-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-nvrtc-dev-8-0 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-runtime-8-0 : Depends: cuda-nvrtc-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
                    Depends: cuda-nvgraph-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
                    Depends: cuda-cusolver-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
                    Depends: cuda-cublas-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
                    Depends: cuda-cufft-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
                    Depends: cuda-curand-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
                    Depends: cuda-cusparse-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
                    Depends: cuda-npp-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
                    Depends: cuda-cudart-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
 cuda-toolkit-8-0 : Depends: cuda-nvml-dev-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
                    Depends: cuda-driver-dev-8-0 (>= 8.0.61) but 8.0.34-1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I'm not sure where the 8.0.34 came from, but now I can't install anything (and I mean anything!!!) and I can't remove Cuda?
Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: This type of question would have a better chance of getting an answer over at http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: What happens when you try to remove the installed `8.0.34-1` version of  `cuda` first?

Comment: How do recommend doing that? It is not a package, and I have no idea where the .34-1 came from

Answer (score 4):

First, you need to remove the old instalation of CUDA:

```
sudo rm -r /usr/local/cuda*
```

Then, go to the NVIDIA website and download the .run file.

Install it with:

```
sh cuda_8.0.27_linux.run --override
```

You should probably get the CudNN files aswell, if you're planning to do some deep learning:
If this is the case, as optional step, you can install CudNN by going in the extracted folder and do:

```
sudo cp lib64/* /usr/local/cuda/lib64/
sudo cp include/* /usr/local/cuda/include/
```

Next, set Environment path variables in .bashrc:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Comment: I had been breaking my head to re-install CUDA. This fixed it. Thanks a ton